# If 3 Products added on Quote & they have 5,10 and 15 % Discount. I want to see average discount of discounts % on Discount custom field on Quote

Tags: formula

I want to see the Average Quote Discount in this field. Let us suppose if there are 3 Products added to the Quote, and they have 5,10 and 15 % Discount. I want to see the average discount on the Discount field that i created on Quote.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/388157/edit) your question to add what you have tried (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating two rollup summary fields on the Quote and then a formula field to calculate the average.
You could do something like this.

1. Create a Rollup Summary field: Sum
2. Create another Rollup Summary: Count
3. Create a formula field: Sum/count

Comment: created but whats after that

Comment: This new formula field on the Quote object will calculate the average discount. It will replace the field that already created.